Alternative characterization of distributive lattice
Let $(X,{\leq},{\wedge},{\vee})$ be a lattice.
The lattice is called distributive if for all $x,y,z\in X$ both distributive laws hold:
$$
x \wedge (y \vee z) = (x \wedge z) \vee (y \wedge z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
x \vee (y \wedge z) = (x \vee z) \wedge (y \wedge z).
$$
According to this Wikipedia article, the lattice $X$ is distributive if and only if for all $x,y,z\in X$,
$$(x \wedge y) \vee (y \wedge z) \vee (z\wedge x) = (x\vee y) \wedge (y \vee z) \wedge (z\vee x).$$
I can do one direction: If $X$ is distributive, then
\begin{align}
(x \wedge y) \vee (y \wedge z) \vee (z\wedge x)
&= (y \wedge (x \vee z)) \vee (z\wedge x) \\
&= (y \vee (z\wedge x)) \wedge ((x\vee z) \vee (z\wedge x)) \\
&= ((y \vee z) \wedge (y \vee x)) \wedge (((x\vee z)\vee z) \wedge ((x \vee z)\vee x)) \\
&= (y \vee z) \wedge (y \vee x) \wedge (x\vee z) \wedge (x \vee z) \\
&= (x\vee y) \wedge (y \vee z) \wedge (z \vee x).
\end{align}
But I'm lost on the reverse implication.
Can anyone show me how to do it?

The straightforward way to prove it is to use the $M_3-N_5$ theorem:

A lattice is distributive iff it doesn't have a copy of either $M_3$ or $N_5$ as a sub-lattice.

The Hasse diagrams of $M_3$ and $N_5$ are in the image here for reference.
You already showed that distributive lattices satisfy the identity
\begin{equation}
(x\wedge y) \vee (y \wedge z) \vee (z \wedge x) = (x\vee y) \wedge (y \vee z) \wedge (z \vee x).
\label{eq1}\tag{$\dagger$}
\end{equation}
So the result is proven if we show that every non-distributive lattice fails to satisfy \eqref{eq1}, and for that, using the $M_3-N_5$ theorem, it's enough to see that both $M_3$ and $N_5$ fail to satisfy \eqref{eq1}.
Indeed, and using the same labels in the image, in $M_3$ that would give $0=1$ and in $N_5$, we would have $x=z$.

Perhaps you were really interested in an equational proof.
Something closer to that is as follows.
(This is very close to a proof in Grätzer, General Lattice Theory, 2nd ed., Theorem III.2.4, page 185.)
Let us start to prove that a lattice satisfying \eqref{eq1} is modular, that is, it satisfies the Modular law:
\begin{equation}
x \leq y \implies x \vee (y \wedge z) = y \wedge (x \vee z)
\tag{M}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}
Indeed, if $x \leq y$, then $x = x \wedge y$ and $(y \wedge z) \vee (z \wedge x) = y \wedge z$, yielding
\begin{align}
x \vee (y \wedge z)
&= (x \wedge y) \vee (y \wedge z) \vee (z \wedge x)\\
&= (x \vee y) \wedge (y \vee z) \wedge (z \vee x) \tag{$\because$\eqref{eq1}}\\
&= y \wedge (x \vee z).
\end{align}
Now, the distributivity:
\begin{align}
x \vee (y \wedge z)
&= x \vee (x \wedge y) \vee (y \wedge z) \vee (z \wedge x) \tag{$\because$ Absorption}\\
&= x \vee ((x \vee y) \wedge (y \vee z) \wedge (z \vee x)) \tag{$\because$ \eqref{eq1}}\\
&= (x \vee y) \wedge (z \vee x) \wedge (x \vee y \vee z) \tag{$\because$ \eqref{eq2}}\\
&= (x \vee y) \wedge (x \vee z),
\end{align}
where the application of Modular law above, follows from $x \leq (x \vee y) \wedge (z \vee x)$ (thanks to @azimut for noticing I had used Modular law twice needlessly).

This is a very nice answer, thank you! Right, I wanted an equational proof. So you first show that the lattice is modular (which is ($\star$)), and then distributive.

@azimut I can't believe I didn't recognize the modular law there! Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit accordingly.

I think in the second part, it can be done with a single application of the modularity law. The application to $x \leq ((x \vee y) \wedge (x\vee z))$ yields $x\vee ((y\vee z) \wedge (x\vee y) \wedge (x\vee z)) = (x\vee y\vee z) \wedge ((x\vee y)\wedge (x\vee z))$.

@azimut I think you are correct! Once again, I'll edit to include your observation. Thanks!
